# Looping through columns in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, loops

I want to execute the following query 3 times for 3 different columns
(pc = t1.postal_code, t1.postal_code_2, t1.postal_code_3).

```
update addresses t1 set
admin_name1 = t.admin_name1,
admin_name2 = t.admin_name2,
admin_name3 = t.admin_name3,
admin_name4 = t.admin_name4,
from (
select * from all_countries) t
where t.postal_code = pc and t1.country_ = t.country      ;
```

Is there are way of writing the code only once, e.g. by means of a loop, and how can I implement it?

Comment: You'd have to use dynamic SQL, and that would probably be uglier than writing the same statement three times.

Comment: No, just no. Read up on normalization then come back

Comment: @NeilMcGuigan This has nothing to do with normalization.